# Angular 2 Material 2 top navbar\toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have the toolbar working but it leaves a gap around instead of smooth at the top of the page.

Also I would like it to be sticky but have not yet worked on that part since it doesn't look like my toolbar implementation is a "header". What am I doing wrong or am I using the wrong component?

[image: Toolbar with gaps]

```html
<md-toolbar color="primary">
    <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
    <span class="app-toolbar-filler"></span>
    <md-sidenav>
    </md-sidenav>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Please check this link i have also implemented the same 
https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Hope it helps

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: My answer is the better way to do it, and will still work if Material changes the way Sidenav works. Please take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The <s>accepted</s> other answer seems kind of hacky, since your toolbar isn't really a sidenav. Here's a better way to do it.

In `styles.css`, set:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

However, this also gets rid of the margins for the rest of the HTML. If you do not want this, wrap the rest of the HTML in a `<div>` and add a margin to that.

Comment: This does work, I did change the menu from a side bar but this will work for the right side as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Simply place your code inside a `md-sidenav-container` element and add an attribute `fullscreen`:

```html
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
        <span class="app-toolbar-filler"></span>
        <md-sidenav>
        </md-sidenav>
    </md-toolbar>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/y1ZgwiMdWeyBk60Zyh5s?p=preview)

**UPDATE:** You should use the answer above mine. It doesn't require a sidenav.

Comment: what is up with all angular plunkr demo's? They never run!

Comment: @devN That's because they use the latest `master` version, which may include breaking changes. Some plunkers may break as a result of this as they include old changes. Do you want me to port the demo to Stackblitz? You should probably use the code above my answer. It's better and doesn't require a sidenav!

Comment: No, it's okay. My issue was not related to this question anyway. Thanks for mentioning stackblitz, never heard of it before, it is awesome!